# ¿Como agregar una diagonal despues de otra, de manera automatizada?

Tags: javascript, regex

lo que me gustaria hacer es poder agregar una doble diagonal cada vez que haya una diagonal simple dentro de mi url que obtengo ya que mi proposito original es guardar la direccion de una imagen en mi base de datos pero solo me guarda un punto y no toda la direccion y a mi punto de vista se debe a la diagonal simple, aunque no estoy seguro.

Codigo .js que inicializar el almacenamiento de la imagen y obtiene la direccion de dicha ruta.

```
guardarImagenP();
    var logo = $("#txtLogoP").text();
```

Codigo para guardar imagen:

```
/* Función para gurdar archivos */
function guardarImagenP() {
    $("#updLogoP").uploadify({
        'swf': '../../../js/system/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
        'uploader': 'subirImagen.ashx',
        'cancelImg': '../../../js/system/uploadify/cancel.png', /// "../../system/uploadify/uploadify.swf"
        'folder': 'bom',
        'auto': true,
        'multi': false,
        'queueSizeLimit': 1,
        'uploadLimit': 1000,
        'fileTypeDesc': 'Archivos jpg', //<-- This can be whatever you want
        'fileTypeExt': '*.jpeg',
        'buttonText': "Seleccionar",
        'onUploadSuccess': function (file, XMLHttpRequest) {
            var ruta = XMLHttpRequest;
            if (XMLHttpRequest != -1) {
                $("#txtLogoP").text(ruta);
                $("#imgLogoP").attr("src", ruta);
            } else {
                alert(XMLHttpRequest)
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para agregar una `/`(diagonal) despues de otra, de manera automatizada usa [Expresiones Regulares](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). Por tratarse de un caracter especial, deberás escaparlo anteponiendo `\`, es decir deberás usar `\/`. Además deberás usar el parámetro `g`, búsqueda global.

Ejemplo

```js
var URL = "http://es.stackoverflow.com/tags";
var re = /\//g;
var resultado = URL.replace(re,'//');
console.log(resultado);
```

Comment: ya realice la forma en que usted dice y si me funciono, lo hice desde javascript, pero aun asi me sigue insertando solo un "." en ese campo de la tabla, ya vi todo el proceso de mi ruta y en el codigo siempre lleva "//" pero al terminar en la insercion solo aparece un punto.